# Using map without executing and combine bind - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bind, array-map

[image: Example]

Could anyone please tell me why this const is a function? And how is this function used like a map? I was having a hard time understanding this code:

```
const something = ['a','b','c'].map.bind([1,2,3]);
```

Thank you 'Euan Smith' for explaining that there are a few ways to get the map -  I checked it now:
[image]

Comment: Because bind returns the same function with new context bound to it... :)

Comment: What that code means is assuming your original array as `arr`, the prototype method map, that you'd call on it will have the value of `this` set to `[1,2,3]`. When called, it will actually call the map function with the value of `this` as `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all the `['a','b','c']` is a distraction.  You would get the same overal resul with `const something = [].map.bind([1,2,3]);`.  That first part of the code is just there to get a reference to the map method of an array.  The same could be obtained with `Array.prototype.map`, but `[].map` takes less typing.

The bind is binding this map function to the array `[1,2,3]`, and that is what `something` is pointing to, a version of the map function bound to `[1,2,3]`.  For example if you called `something(v=>v*2)` you would get back `[2,4,6]`.

Check out the MDN pages for [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [Array~map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and [Function~bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is function on `Array.prototype` types assigned on its prototype inheritance structure.

It is just a plain JS function with no object assigned to it. Using `bind` we are binding the map function to a particular object, here `[1,2,3]`